# is there a parameter to set the precision for numpy.linspace?

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to check if a `numpy` array contains a specific value:

```
>>> x = np.linspace(-5,5,101)
>>> x
array([-5. , -4.9, -4.8, -4.7, -4.6, -4.5, -4.4, -4.3, -4.2, -4.1, -4. ,
       -3.9, -3.8, -3.7, -3.6, -3.5, -3.4, -3.3, -3.2, -3.1, -3. , -2.9,
       -2.8, -2.7, -2.6, -2.5, -2.4, -2.3, -2.2, -2.1, -2. , -1.9, -1.8,
       -1.7, -1.6, -1.5, -1.4, -1.3, -1.2, -1.1, -1. , -0.9, -0.8, -0.7,
       -0.6, -0.5, -0.4, -0.3, -0.2, -0.1,  0. ,  0.1,  0.2,  0.3,  0.4,
        0.5,  0.6,  0.7,  0.8,  0.9,  1. ,  1.1,  1.2,  1.3,  1.4,  1.5,
        1.6,  1.7,  1.8,  1.9,  2. ,  2.1,  2.2,  2.3,  2.4,  2.5,  2.6,
        2.7,  2.8,  2.9,  3. ,  3.1,  3.2,  3.3,  3.4,  3.5,  3.6,  3.7,
        3.8,  3.9,  4. ,  4.1,  4.2,  4.3,  4.4,  4.5,  4.6,  4.7,  4.8,
        4.9,  5. ])
>>> -5. in x
True
>>> a = 0.2
>>> a
0.2
>>> a in x
False
```

I assigned a constant to variable `a`. It seems that the precision of `a` is not compatible with the elements in the `numpy` array generated by `np.linspace()`.

I've searched the [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linspace.html), but didn't find anything about this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is not a question of the precision of `np.linspace`, but rather of the *type of the elements in the generated array*.

`np.linspace` generates elements which, conceptually, equally divide the input range between them. However, these elements are then stored as floating point numbers with limited precision, which makes the generation process itself appear to lack precision.

By passing the `dtype` argument to `np.linspace`, you can specify the precision of the floating point type used to store its result, which can increase the *apparent* precision of the generation process.

Nevertheless, [you should not use the equality operator to compare floating point numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken). Instead, use `np.isclose` in conjunction with `np.ndarray.any`, or some equivalent:

```
>>> floats_64 = np.linspace(-5, 5, 101, dtype='float64')
>>> floats_128 = np.linspace(-5, 5, 101, dtype='float128')
>>> print(0.2 in floats_64)
False
>>> print(floats_64[52])
0.20000000000000018
>>> print(np.isclose(0.2, floats_64).any())  # check if any element in floats_64 is close to 0.2
True
>>> print(0.2 in floats_128)
False
>>> print(floats_128[52])
0.20000000000000017764
>>> print(np.isclose(0.2, floats_128).any())  # check if any element in floats_128 is close to 0.2
True
```